# Do I've to create a new function for every meta box field?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am still trying to learn how to build a comprehensive plugin in Wordpress, and Im having issues with meta boxes.

If its possible I would like to have multiple fields in the same metabox, both for aeasthetic reasons but also so I am not writing a new callback function for every single metabox.

Is this possible?

Here is my current code (leaving out the registering of the post type and save function).

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'ALCI_member_setup' );

function ALCI_member_setup() {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'ALCI_members_create_metaboxes' );
}

function ALCI_members_create_metaboxes()
{   
   add_meta_box('ALCI_member_qualification', 'Member Qualifications', 'ALCI_member_qualification', 'ALCI-members', 'normal', 'high');   
}

function ALCI_member_qualification() {

  global $post;
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="ALCI_member_qualification_noncename" id="ALCI_member_qualification_noncename" value="' .
  wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

  $qualification = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ALCI_member_qualification', true);

  echo '<p>Qualifications that appear beside the members name, e.g. BSc (Hons) IBCLC</p> 
  <input type="text" name="ALCI_member_qualification" value="' . $qualification  . '" class="widefat" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is absolutely possible.

Simply add the rest of your meta fields in the `ALCI_member_qualification()` and then add the save functions for them and it should work just the same.

Comment: Thank you, so would I need a separate save function for each one yes?

Comment: actually I got the save function to work with a for loop going through each input field, thanks